# Undefined sequece error when use the math environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

When I am trying to code in the math mode, the compiling process is terminated under any environment. How may I solve it?

```
\begin{document}
Let $\mathbf{A}$ be the set of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that 
equation
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please make this into a full minimal example. Document class and preamble is missing. Might also be a good idea to cite the actual error message. Given what you have here my guess is that you have forgotten to load amssymb or any similar package that provides `\mathbb`

Comment: Load `amsfonts`?!

Comment: Please check the exact error message. Does it maybe say "`! Undefined control sequence.`" rather than "`Undefined sequence error`"?

Comment: Thank you all for your kind assistance, it turned out that the problem is incurred simply because I didn't use the packages, I'll also try harder to state more clearly the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already commented, you almost certainly failed to load the `amssymb` package in the preamble of your document. (Aside: The `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically.) For sure, the following example, which loads the `amssymb` package, compiles without any problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % <-- important
\begin{document}
Let $\mathbf{A}$ be the set of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!